# Keyboard filter driver unload BSOD

Tags: windows, keyboard, kernel, driver, bsod

I have developed a keyboard filter driver that changes the keyboard button '1' (above the Q button) to '2'.

This driver works fine.

However, after Unload is executed, pressing the keyboard button causes BSOD.

If the driver is loaded and unloaded without pressing the keyboard button, it will be unloaded normally.

When I check it with Windbg, my driver's ReadCompletion () function is called even after it is unloaded.

I do not know why this is happening even though I've called IoDetachDevice () and IoDeleteDevice ().

In addition, after loading the driver, if you press the keyboard button '1' at the beginning, it does not change to '2'.

And then it changes very well.

I do not know what this is related to.

I hope you will find a solution to this problem.

please answer about my question.

Below is the source code.

```
#include <wdm.h>

typedef struct
{
    PDEVICE_OBJECT NextLayerDeviceObject;
} DEVICE_EXTENSION, *PDEVICE_EXTENSION;

const WCHAR next_device_name[] = L"\\Device\\KeyboardClass0";

const char dbg_name[] = "[Test]";

NTSTATUS IrpSkip(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
    NTSTATUS ret = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION Stack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    DbgPrint("%s IrpSkip() Start\n", dbg_name);
    DbgPrint("%s IrpSkip() - MajorFunction %d\n", dbg_name, Stack->MajorFunction);

    IoSkipCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    ret = IoCallDriver(((PDEVICE_EXTENSION)(DeviceObject->DeviceExtension))->NextLayerDeviceObject, Irp);
    DbgPrint("IoCallDriver return %x\n", ret);
    DbgPrint("%s IrpSkip() End\n", dbg_name);

    return ret;
}

NTSTATUS ReadCompletion(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp, IN PVOID Context)
{
    NTSTATUS ret = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION Stack;
    unsigned char key[32];

    DbgPrint("%s ReadCompletion() Start\n", dbg_name);

    if (Irp->IoStatus.Status == STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        DbgPrint("%s ReadCompletion() - Success\n", dbg_name);
        RtlCopyMemory(key, Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer, 32);
        DbgPrint("%s Data : %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", dbg_name, key[0], key[1], key[2], key[3], key[4], key[5], key[6], key[7]);
        if (key[2] == 2)
        {
            key[2] = 3;
            RtlCopyMemory(Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer, key, 32);
            DbgPrint("%s Key '1' changed '2'\n", dbg_name);
        }
    }
    //else if (Irp->IoStatus.Status == STATUS_PENDING)
    else
    {
        DbgPrint("%s ReadCompletion() - Fail... %x\n", Irp->IoStatus.Status);
    }

    if (Irp->PendingReturned)
    {
        IoMarkIrpPending(Irp);
    }

    DbgPrint("%s ReadCompletion() End\n", dbg_name);

    return Irp->IoStatus.Status;
}

NTSTATUS Read(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
    NTSTATUS ret = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION Stack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    DbgPrint("%s Read() Start\n", dbg_name);

    PDEVICE_EXTENSION device_extension = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION)DeviceObject->DeviceExtension;

    //IoCopyCurrentIrpStackLocationToNext(Irp);
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION current_irp = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION next_irp = IoGetNextIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    *next_irp = *current_irp;

    IoSetCompletionRoutine(Irp, ReadCompletion, DeviceObject, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);

    ret=IoCallDriver(((PDEVICE_EXTENSION)device_extension)->NextLayerDeviceObject, Irp);

    DbgPrint("%s Read() End\n", dbg_name);

    return ret;
}

NTSTATUS Unload(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    NTSTATUS ret = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    IoDetachDevice(((PDEVICE_EXTENSION)(DriverObject->DeviceObject->DeviceExtension))->NextLayerDeviceObject);
    IoDeleteDevice(DriverObject->DeviceObject);

    DbgPrint("%s Unload()...\n", dbg_name);

    return ret;
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    NTSTATUS ret=STATUS_SUCCESS;
    UNICODE_STRING _next_device_name;

    DbgSetDebugFilterState(DPFLTR_DEFAULT_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, TRUE);

    DbgPrint("%s DriverEntry() Start\n", dbg_name);

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&_next_device_name, next_device_name);

    for (int i = 0; i < IRP_MJ_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION ; i++)
    {
        DriverObject->MajorFunction[i] = IrpSkip;
    }
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = Unload;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_READ] = Read;

    PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject = 0;
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION DeviceExtension;

    ret = IoCreateDevice(DriverObject, sizeof(DEVICE_EXTENSION), 0, FILE_DEVICE_KEYBOARD, 0, TRUE, &DeviceObject);
    if (ret == STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        DbgPrint("%s DriverEntry() - IoCreateDevice() Success\n", dbg_name);
    }
    else
    {
        DbgPrint("%s DriverEntry() - IoCreateDevice() Fail\n", dbg_name);
        return ret;
    }
    DeviceExtension = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION)DeviceObject->DeviceExtension;
    DeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;
    DeviceObject->Flags |= (DO_BUFFERED_IO | DO_POWER_PAGABLE);

    ret = IoAttachDevice(DeviceObject, &_next_device_name, &DeviceExtension->NextLayerDeviceObject);
    if (ret == STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        DbgPrint("%s DriverEntry() - IoAttachDevice() Success\n", dbg_name);
    }
    else
    {
        DbgPrint("%s DriverEntry() - IoAttachDevice() Fail\n", dbg_name);
        IoDeleteDevice(DriverObject->DeviceObject);
        return ret;
    }

    DbgPrint("%s DriverEntry() End\n", dbg_name);

    return ret;
}
```

Below is Windbg Call Stack.

```
0: kd> k
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 82f33604 82eea083 nt!RtlpBreakWithStatusInstruction
01 82f33654 82eeab81 nt!KiBugCheckDebugBreak+0x1c
02 82f33a1c 82e4c5cb nt!KeBugCheck2+0x68b
03 82f33a1c 975e36e0 nt!KiTrap0E+0x2cf
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
04 82f33aac 82e83933 <Unloaded_Test.sys>+0x16e0
05 82f33af0 8efed7a2 nt!IopfCompleteRequest+0x128
06 82f33b14 8eea7b74 kbdclass!KeyboardClassServiceCallback+0x2fa
07 82f33b78 82e831b5 i8042prt!I8042KeyboardIsrDpc+0x18c
08 82f33bd4 82e83018 nt!KiExecuteAllDpcs+0xf9
09 82f33c20 82e82e38 nt!KiRetireDpcList+0xd5
0a 82f33c24 00000000 nt!KiIdleLoop+0x38
```

The CallBack function does not seem to be released properly.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you pass pointer to own driver body (`ReadCompletion` in your case) - driver must not be unloaded until this pointer is used (`ReadCompletion` called and returned your case)

as notified *Harry Johnston* need use [`IoSetCompletionRoutineEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549686(v=vs.85).aspx) - but documentation for this is bad and not explain all details. absolute mandatory study windows src files (`WRK-v1.2` for example) and binary windows code. if you look for implementation of [`IoSetCompletionRoutineEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549686(v=vs.85).aspx) - you can view that this routine **nothing do** for prevent you driver for unloading. it simply allocate small memory block, save here your `DeviceObject`, `Context` and `CompletionRoutine` and set `IopUnloadSafeCompletion` as completion and pointer to allocated memory block as context.

what is `IopUnloadSafeCompletion` doing ?

```
NTSTATUS
IopUnloadSafeCompletion(
    IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
    IN PIRP Irp,
    IN PVOID Context
    )
{
    PIO_UNLOAD_SAFE_COMPLETION_CONTEXT Usc = Context;
    NTSTATUS Status;

    ObReferenceObject (Usc->DeviceObject);

    Status = Usc->CompletionRoutine (DeviceObject, Irp, Usc->Context);

    ObDereferenceObject (Usc->DeviceObject);
    ExFreePool (Usc);
    return Status;
}
```

but this assume that `Usc->DeviceObject` **IS VALID** at calling `IopUnloadSafeCompletion` time. you can delete/de-reference `DeviceObject` inside `CompletionRoutine` , do some task which cause your driver unload - and will be no crash, because your `CompletionRoutine` protected by adding reference to your device. but if `IopUnloadSafeCompletion` will be called when your device already destroyed and driver unloaded - any way will be crash.

*partial* solution will be call `ObfReferenceObject(DeviceObject)` in your dispatch routine and `ObfDereferenceObject(DeviceObject)` in completion routine. this on practice resolve problem. so code must be next

```
NTSTATUS OnComplete(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp, PVOID /*Context*/)
{
    ObfDereferenceObject(DeviceObject);// !!!

    PIO_STACK_LOCATION IrpSp = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    if (Irp->PendingReturned)
    {
        IrpSp->Control |= SL_PENDING_RETURNED;
    }

    if (IrpSp->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_READ &&
        Irp->IoStatus.Status == STATUS_SUCCESS && 
        (Irp->Flags & IRP_BUFFERED_IO))
    {
        if (ULONG n = (ULONG)Irp->IoStatus.Information / sizeof(KEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA))
        {
            PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA pkid = (PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;

            do 
            {
                DbgPrint("Port%x> %x %x\n", pkid->UnitId, pkid->MakeCode, pkid->Flags);
            } while (pkid++, --n);
        }
    }

    return ContinueCompletion;
}

NTSTATUS KbdDispatch(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp)
{
    IoCopyCurrentIrpStackLocationToNext(Irp);

    if (0 > IoSetCompletionRoutineEx(DeviceObject, Irp, OnComplete, NULL, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))
    {
        IoSkipCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    }
    else
    {
        ObfReferenceObject(DeviceObject);// !!!
    }

    return IofCallDriver(
        reinterpret_cast<DEVICE_EXTENSION*>(DeviceObject->DeviceExtension)->_NextDeviceObject, Irp);
}
```

call `ObfReferenceObject(DeviceObject);` in `KbdDispatch` prevent unload your driver until `ObfDereferenceObject(DeviceObject);` called inside `OnComplete`.

you can ask for what in this case [`IoSetCompletionRoutineEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549686(v=vs.85).aspx) at all, if we yourself call `ObfReferenceObject` / `ObfDereferenceObject` ? because if `DriverUnload` already called - all your code hold only on single reference on `DeviceObject` - so when you call `ObfDereferenceObject(DeviceObject);` from `OnComplete` - your device will be deleted and driver unloaded inside `ObfDereferenceObject` and finally this routine returned to your **unloaded** code. so sense of [`IoSetCompletionRoutineEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549686(v=vs.85).aspx) is protect your completion routine.

but need understand that this is anyway not 100% correct solution. call `IoDetachDevice/IoDeleteDevice` for attached device not correct from `DriverUnload`. ( *this must be called from `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` or `FAST_IO_DETACH_DEVICE` callback*)

assume next scenario - somebody call `NtReadFile` for device `A` to which your `B` device is attached. `NtReadFile` get pointer to your `B` device via `IoGetRelatedDeviceObject`. internally this routine call [`IoGetAttachedDevice`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548359(v=vs.85).aspx). read this:

> *IoGetAttachedDevice* does not increment the reference count on the
>   device object. (Thus no matching call to *ObDereferenceObject* is
>   required.) Callers of *IoGetAttachedDevice* must ensure that no device
>   objects are added to or removed from the stack while
>   *IoGetAttachedDevice* is executing. Callers that cannot do this must use
>   *IoGetAttachedDeviceReference* instead.

assume that while `NtReadFile` using pointer to your `B` device, another thread called your `DriverUnload` which delete `B` device and unload driver. handle/file object exist on device `A` - this hold it and prevent from unloading. but your attached `B` device **not hold nothing**. as result if `NtReadFile` or any another I/O subsystem routine which use your device execute in concurrent with `DriverUnload` where you call detach/delete device - system can crash already inside `NtReadFile` code. and you nothing can do with this. only one way after call `IoDetachDevice` some(how many ?!) time wait before call `IoDeleteDevice`. fortunately possibility of this case very low usual.

so try understand - system can crash in  `NtReadFile` already. even if your Dispatch called - your `DeviceObject` can be deleted/not valid already or driver unloaded during dispatch routine. only after you call `ObfReferenceObject(DeviceObject)` all become ok. and all this problem because you try detach attached device in DriverUnload (windows not designed for this).

also can noted many another errors in your code. say completion routine must not return `Irp->IoStatus.Status` it must return or `StopCompletion` (i.e `STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED` ) or any another value - usual `ContinueCompletion` (i.e `STATUS_CONTINUE_COMPLETION` or 0) also need not hardcode `"\\Device\\KeyboardClass0"` but use `IoRegisterPlugPlayNotification` with `GUID_CLASS_KEYBOARD` if you not wdm driver. also for xp need special handler for `IRP_MJ_POWER` ( [Passing Power IRPs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558785(v=vs.85).aspx) ) but may be this is already not actual if xp support not actual.

code example can be look like:

```
struct DEVICE_EXTENSION
{
    PDEVICE_OBJECT _NextDeviceObject;
};

NTSTATUS KbdPower(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp)
{
    PoStartNextPowerIrp(Irp);

    IoSkipCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    return PoCallDriver(
        reinterpret_cast<DEVICE_EXTENSION*>(DeviceObject->DeviceExtension)->_NextDeviceObject, Irp);
}

NTSTATUS OnComplete(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp, PVOID /*Context*/)
{
    ObfDereferenceObject(DeviceObject);

    PIO_STACK_LOCATION IrpSp = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    if (Irp->PendingReturned)
    {
        IrpSp->Control |= SL_PENDING_RETURNED;
    }

    if (IrpSp->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_READ &&
        Irp->IoStatus.Status == STATUS_SUCCESS && 
        (Irp->Flags & IRP_BUFFERED_IO))
    {
        if (ULONG n = (ULONG)Irp->IoStatus.Information / sizeof(KEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA))
        {
            PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA pkid = (PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;

            do 
            {
                DbgPrint("Port%x> %x %x\n", pkid->UnitId, pkid->MakeCode, pkid->Flags);
            } while (pkid++, --n);
        }
    }

    return ContinueCompletion;
}

NTSTATUS KbdDispatch(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp)
{
    IoCopyCurrentIrpStackLocationToNext(Irp);

    if (0 > IoSetCompletionRoutineEx(DeviceObject, Irp, OnComplete, NULL, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))
    {
        IoSkipCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    }
    else
    {
        ObfReferenceObject(DeviceObject);
    }

    return IofCallDriver(
        reinterpret_cast<DEVICE_EXTENSION*>(DeviceObject->DeviceExtension)->_NextDeviceObject, Irp);
}

NTSTATUS KbdNotifyCallback(PDEVICE_INTERFACE_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION Notification, PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    if (::RtlCompareMemory(&Notification->Event, &GUID_DEVICE_INTERFACE_ARRIVAL, sizeof(GUID)) == sizeof(GUID))
    {
        DbgPrint("++%wZ\n", Notification->SymbolicLinkName);

        HANDLE hFile;
        OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, Notification->SymbolicLinkName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

        if (0 <= IoCreateFile(&hFile, SYNCHRONIZE, &oa, &iosb, 0, 0, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_OPEN, 0, 0, 0, CreateFileTypeNone, 0, IO_ATTACH_DEVICE))
        {
            PFILE_OBJECT FileObject;

            NTSTATUS status = ObReferenceObjectByHandle(hFile, 0, 0, 0, (void**)&FileObject, 0);

            NtClose(hFile);

            if (0 <= status)
            {
                PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, TargetDevice = IoGetAttachedDeviceReference(FileObject->DeviceObject);

                ObfDereferenceObject(FileObject);

                if (0 <= IoCreateDevice(DriverObject, sizeof(DEVICE_EXTENSION), 0, 
                    TargetDevice->DeviceType, 
                    TargetDevice->Characteristics & (FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA|FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN), 
                    FALSE, &DeviceObject))
                {
                    DeviceObject->Flags |= TargetDevice->Flags & 
                        (DO_BUFFERED_IO|DO_DIRECT_IO|DO_SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS|DO_POWER_PAGABLE|DO_POWER_INRUSH);

                    DEVICE_EXTENSION* pExt = (DEVICE_EXTENSION*)DeviceObject->DeviceExtension;

                    if (0 > IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStackSafe(DeviceObject, TargetDevice, &pExt->_NextDeviceObject))
                    {
                        IoDeleteDevice(DeviceObject);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;

                        DbgPrint("++DeviceObject<%p> %x\n", DeviceObject, DeviceObject->Flags);
                    }
                }

                ObfDereferenceObject(TargetDevice);
            }
        }
    }

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

PVOID NotificationEntry;

void KbdUnload(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    DbgPrint("KbdUnload(%p)\n", DriverObject);

    if (NotificationEntry) IoUnregisterPlugPlayNotification(NotificationEntry);

    PDEVICE_OBJECT NextDevice = DriverObject->DeviceObject, DeviceObject;

    while (DeviceObject = NextDevice)
    {
        NextDevice = DeviceObject->NextDevice;
        DbgPrint("--DeviceObject<%p>\n", DeviceObject);
        IoDetachDevice(reinterpret_cast<DEVICE_EXTENSION*>(DeviceObject->DeviceExtension)->_NextDeviceObject);
        IoDeleteDevice(DeviceObject);
    }
}

NTSTATUS KbdInit(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING /*RegistryPath*/)
{       
    DbgPrint("KbdInit(%p)\n", DriverObject);

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = KbdUnload;

#ifdef _WIN64
    __stosq
#else
    __stosd
#endif
        ((PULONG_PTR)DriverObject->MajorFunction, (ULONG_PTR)KbdDispatch, RTL_NUMBER_OF(DriverObject->MajorFunction));

    ULONG MajorVersion;
    PsGetVersion(&MajorVersion, 0, 0, 0);
    if (MajorVersion < 6) DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_POWER] = KbdPower; 

    IoRegisterPlugPlayNotification(
        EventCategoryDeviceInterfaceChange,
        PNPNOTIFY_DEVICE_INTERFACE_INCLUDE_EXISTING_INTERFACES,
        (void*)&GUID_CLASS_KEYBOARD, DriverObject,
        (PDRIVER_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK_ROUTINE)KbdNotifyCallback,
        DriverObject, &NotificationEntry);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.
I can not do it now, so I will reply if I try later.

Comment: @SlayerBae - briefly if you replace `IoSetCompletionRoutine` to `IoSetCompletionRoutineEx` you anyway got BSOD in same place. but if you call `ObfReferenceObject(DeviceObject)` after success call `IoSetCompletionRoutineEx` and `ObfDereferenceObject(DeviceObject);` in `ReadCompletion` this solve the problem in practice. but strictly speaking code anyway incorrect and *can* crash in `NtReadFile` or at very begin of your dispatch routine (before call `ObfReferenceObject(DeviceObject)` ).

Comment: I studied a little more and now I understood. Thank you for your kind answer. It was a great help.

Comment: @RbMm thank you for the reply, it helped me very much. I believe you'd better add `OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE` along with `OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE`, is that right? Also, why not use `IoGetDeviceObjectPointer` instead of `IoCreateFile` + ... + `IoGetAttachedDeviceReference`?

Comment: @Paul - `OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE` place handle to system process handle table, as result it can be accessed from arbitrary context. in my code i just close handle, after open, so context not problem here. by fact effect will be the same. `IoCreateFile` i use for `IO_ATTACH_DEVICE`. the `IoGetDeviceObjectPointer` by unknow reason not use this. so can fail for say exclusive open devices

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it explains your problem:

> **Note**   Only a driver that can guarantee it will not be unloaded before its completion routine finishes can use IoSetCompletionRoutine. Otherwise, the driver must use IoSetCompletionRoutineEx, which prevents the driver from unloading until its completion routine executes.

(From the [MSDN documentation for IoSetCompletionRoutine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549679(v=vs.85).aspx).)

---

PS: the one-keystroke delay in the functionality taking effect is to be expected, because your driver isn't hooked into the read operation that was already in progress when it was loaded.  I'm not sure whether there's any reasonable way to do that.

Comment: I've used IoSetCompletionRoutineEx () instead of IoSetCompletionRoutine ()
but another blue screen happens.

Comment: I believe that would properly be a separate question.

Comment: @SlayerBae - yes, must be BSOD by same reason - this is not separate question. use `IoSetCompletionRoutineEx` correct but not sufficient way. you need more deep understand what is under the hood and use rundown protections or removal locks. little bit later i post own answer