# How to obtain the handle to keyboard device?

Tags: windows, assembly, keyboard, x86-64

I am trying to hook keyboard ISR, but I can't open the device because 
`CreateFile` returns `0000007Bh ERROR_INVALID_NAME`. What have I done incorrectly?

```
invoke DefineDosDevice,[raw],filename1,devicename
lea     rcx,[filename2]
invoke  CreateFileA,rcx,GENERIC_ALL,FILE_SHARE_WRITE or 
FILE_SHARE_READ,0,3,0,0
ret

section '.data' data writeable readable

devicename      db '\\Device\\KeyboardClass0',0
filename1       db 'keyboard',0
filename2       db '\\.\keyboard',0
raw             dq      1
```

Comment: Based on the format of the string `devicename` your assembler is interpreting the backslashes as escape characters. Have you tried `\\\\.\\keyboard` for `filename2`?

Comment: It dont works. My assembler dont interpret the backslashes in that way.

Comment: There's no device that you can open that will allow you to hook the keyboard ISR. That simply can't be don't from a user mode process, it's something you'd need to from a driver. However even from a driver, ISR hooking is prevented through Kernel Patch Protection on modern versions of Windows. From a driver you can use a I8042prt filter instead, but note this wouldn't work USB keyboards (which don't have their own dedicated keyboard IRQ). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/hid/3rd-party-filter-drivers

Comment: @Ross, a kernel-mode driver can sit as an upper filter to kbdclass, see, e.g., [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42848364/886887).  Not quite the same thing as intercepting the ISR, but I think you can get much the same functionality.  In principle I think you could also sit between usbhid and kbdclass, in much the same way that the sample you mentioned sits between i8042prt and kbdclass.  This does all seem to need to be kernel-mode though, I've been experimenting with UMDF but so far I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is flat assembler syntax, you should pass `devicename` without escaping back slashes:

```
devicename      db '\Device\KeyboardClass0',0
```

There's also a good [tutorial with source code in C](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/keyboard/article.php/c2825/Manipulating-the-Keyboard-Lights-in-Windows-NT.htm) about how to access keyboard device in Windows. You might find it interesting.

Translating it to assembly, you'll want to do something like

```
include 'include\win64ax.inc'

.code 

start:
  invoke DefineDosDevice, 1, kbdFileName, kbdDeviceName
  mov rcx, kbdPath
  invoke  CreateFile, rcx, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0
  mov [hKbd], rax
  ;. . .
  invoke ExitProcess, 0

.end start 

.data 
kbdDeviceName  db '\Device\KeyboardClass0',0
kbdFileName    db 'kbd',0
kbdPath        db '\\.\kbd',0
hKbd           dq ?
```

Comment: Thanks for answer me, the first problem solved but now I CreateFile get: ERROR_ACCES_DENIED when I try to open keyboard device. Why it happen???

Comment: Probably it's because of Windows security policy. Maybe you need to run as Administrator or something

Comment: I already run as administrator. I think that \Device\KeyboardClass0 is not the correct handle to the keyboard device. What is teh correct handle to device to I hook keyboard ISR???

Comment: Thanks Alexander Zhak for your help. I already solve my problem and now I can hook keyboard ISR

Comment: Now i need the number of `IOCTL_INTERNAL_I8042_HOOK_KEYBOARD` constant. What is this number?